# Help Showing Subspace Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

We are given the vector space of functions $F=\{f:  f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\}$ and the subset $W$, the set of real-valued polynomials.

I'm having trouble determining if $W$ is a vector subspace of $F$.

Comment: Do you know what do you have to check?

Comment: I determined it! You should definitely try it!

Comment: My answer should give you the information you need - but next time try more on your own. This one follows pretty simply from definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Express a general polynomial in the form
$$ \sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$$
for some choice of $n$, where all $a_0,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$. Now: can you express the sum of two polynomials in the same way? How about a scalar multiple of a polynomial? Finally, is $0$ of the form
$$ \sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i.$$
If you can answer these questions, you're done.